# How to sort each facet inidividually in Python Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a data I want to present as horizontal barchart for both row and column facets and a hue. Here is a stylized example of my setting:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.bar(df, x="total_bill", y="day", orientation='h', facet_row="time", facet_col="sex", color="smoker", 
             barmode="group")

fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)
fig.show()
```

This is the resulting figure:

[image]

I would like to sort each facet by values. I was able to do that in *matplotlib* but in *plotly* I haven't found a nice way for that yet. E.g. sorting the dataframe in various ways doesn't yield the result. For example, I could like to sort each facet by non-smoker values in descending order. Then orders of every y-axis ticks should adjust and sorting of male and female y-axis would differ. Is there a way to do this? I also noticed the Dinner row has already different y-axis for males and females, but for males the y-axis values are unclear.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of what you describe, all you have to do is presort the data frame.  Effectively have sorted by facet dimensions, then color, then y (as it's horizontal orientation) and finally by x

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
df = df.sort_values( ["time", "sex", "smoker", "day","total_bill",   ], ascending=[1,1,1,1,0])

fig = px.bar(df, x="total_bill", y="day", orientation='h', facet_row="time", facet_col="sex", color="smoker", 
             barmode="group")

fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this is not what I'm after. E.g. see the Female-Dinner and Male-Lunch facets. They are not sorted the same way as the rest.

Comment: do you mean you want it sorted by the aggregate bar, so in each subplot the longest bar is first, 2nd longest 2nd,  etc ?

Comment: No. I mean I want to sort them by non-smokers, i.e. the blue bars. The longest blue bar in a facet would come on top.